# How to simply view a previous version using git without revert or reset?

Tags: git

Git newb here. I want to use git for version control of writing, not codes.

If you want to view an earlier version in either a branch or a master, how do you open the file and view it? Eg. if you're on writing draft 2 but want to view some of the things you wrote and deleted in writing draft 1, how would you get draft 1 to open in, say, MS Word? And then return to draft 2.

Revert appears to make later commits invisible under "git log", and reset justs erases everything after the commit that you select.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to use `git checkout` and its many options. You can checkout a specific file at its state at a specific commit. Maybe you could have a look for yourself, before one starts to post a more detailed answer. Most certainly, `git revert` is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Going back in history

You can go back a specific point of history with `git checkout` and there are two easy ways to use it:

- `git log` and `git checkout commit_id`
- `git checkout HEAD~number_of_commits_you_want_to_go_back` e.g. `git checkout HEAD~1`.

*Pay extra care to remember to go back to the future once you're finished looking at the old version.* You can do that with `git checkout HEAD` or `git checkout name_of_branch`.

## Two at the same time?

If you would like to use both the current and some other version of the file you will need to: 
   * have two copies of the repository since you can only have one working tree checked out
   * make a copy of the current version before you use `git checkout`

## Little help from the site that hosts your repo

Sites that provide git services often allow you to explore the history of files in your browser and often download the individual file or the entire repo at a given point.

Comment: I'm getting these error messages when I try to move back to the future using both of your methods:

<filename>: needs merge,

error: you need to resolve your current index first

Comment: This means that you made changes when you were in past! You can `git checkout -b my_changes_when_I_was_in_the_past` then commit your changes to this new 'temporary' branch and then `git checkout name_of_original_branch_here(master?)`  to be back in the future.

Comment: Oh my, that makes sense. Thank you. Also, do you have a recommendation for a free site with a friendly UI that has git services? (Not github. I will learn that down the line.)

Comment: No, sorry, I couldn't recommend anything. Having said that, using github, or other site, before mastering `git` is not wrong - it actually may be the best way!

Answer (score 2):

**Detach `HEAD`**

To inspect the state of your application at some given commit, the default would be to just

```
git checkout <commitHash>
```

It will detach `HEAD`, and your working tree will be made to match that commit's tree.

You'll be able to come back to any branch with another `checkout`.

**Temporary branch**

Of course, you could very well prefer to take advantage of git's light branching architecture, and create a branch at the point you want to inspect, it will be as quick to delete it as it was to create it.

```
# creation
git checkout -b <nameForYourTempBranch> <commitHash>
# deletion
git checkout <otherBranch>
git branch -D <nameForYourTempBranch>
```

---

However, in the case you want to keep the current state of the working tree unchanged for some reason, maybe consider adding a (temporary) new worktree. You can do that with

```
git worktree add <path/to/subdir> <commitHash>
```

It will allow you to make this inspection without modifying the current state of your main working tree.

Comment: Okay, I've tried creating a new branch with an old version. That worked. But when I say "git checkout master" to return to the master, then I get the error messages:

"<filename>: needs merge,
error: you need to resolve your current index first" but I don't WANT to merge. I'm happy with just deleting the temporary branch. Also, where can I learn more about the worktree? That's the first I've heard of it, despite watching some beginner tutorials. Sounds neat.

Comment: Nevermind, @tymtam below helped me with the error! So my only question left is about the worktree. Thanks!